# how to run, python script with external libs, and use only venv

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I write some host monitoring script on python2.7 + rrdtool lib.
And I have question: "how to run python script with external lib when I don't have installed pip on linux", "external libs" I mean not standard libs installed python 2.7.

1. I try to use python virtual python-virtual-environments
2. also I try to use activate_this.py
3. and I try to use pip from env directory but I have error - bad python bad interpreter: no such file or directory

And my main question is how to use python and pip only from python-virtual-environments, without system python and system libs.

GitHub link for code: https://github.com/ArtemKyrylov/Internet_monitor

Answer (score 0):

copy the library in Internet_monitor/python-virtual-environments/env/lib/python2.7 and import that in your python script

Comment: Hi Ali, what you mean import, add this LIB as system path or something else? Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: you're welcome Merser5. if you want to use external library in your virtualenv, just put it into Internet_monitor/python-virtual-environments/env/lib/python2.7 and use it.

Comment: Hi Ali, I have problem with import, still similar problem

Comment: you need to install python-rrdtool in your system
apt install python-rrdtool
and path/Internet_monitor/linux_run.sh